# Allow domain user to turn off Windows Defender Firewall

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall

I need to grant all Windows Domain Users (so without elevated privileges) the ability to turn on or off the Windows Defender Firewall and to create exceptions as well.

As far as I remember, I achieved this some years ago injecting the user into the "Network Configuration Operators" group through a GPO...in this way they were allowed to do so but it seems that this trick is not working anymore.

Any suggestion to do so? All the OU computers are Windows 10 and the Domain Controller is a Windows Server 2019 1809. The machine on which I'm testing is a Windows 10 20H2.